# Linear transformation of correlated random variables with zero mean.

Tags: matrices, probability-distributions, random-variables

Question: We are given that $X_1,X_2$ are two random variables with $E(X_1)=E(X_2)=0$ and are correlated.

Suppose $X=\binom{X_1}{X_2}$ and $Y=AX$ for some matrix $A$. Our question is to determine a requirement for $A^TA$ such that elements of $Y$ are uncorrelated and the variance of each element is 1.

My approach: Since $Y=\binom{Y_1}{Y_2}=AX$, we know that the covariance matrix of $Y$ can be given by $$\begin{bmatrix} \sigma^2_{Y_1}&\sigma_{Y_1Y_2} \\ \sigma_{Y_1Y_2} & \sigma^2_{Y_2}\end{bmatrix} = A^T\begin{bmatrix} \sigma^2_{X_1}&\sigma_{X_1X_2} \\ \sigma_{X_1X_2} & \sigma^2_{X_2}\end{bmatrix}A$$
Since the elements of $Y$ are uncorrelated and the variance of each element is 1,
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1&0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} = I = A^T\begin{bmatrix} \sigma^2_{X_1}&\sigma_{X_1X_2} \\ \sigma_{X_1X_2} & \sigma^2_{X_2}\end{bmatrix}A$$
So that implies that $A^TC_xA=I$, in which $C_X$ is the covariance matrix of $X$.

I'm not quite sure how to proceed with the requirement for $A^TA$. I'm thinking of relating this to quadratic form but I have only seen the case in which the middle matrix is a vector, not a 2 by 2 matrix. Are there some simpler properties of matrix transpose that I'm missing here?

Also, sorry in advance if there is any incorrect notation. I'm quite new to this topic.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a bit on how to arrive at that?

Comment: All matrices are square and inverses commute so  $(AA^T)C_x= A(A^TC_x) = (A^TC_x)A = A^TC_xA=I$ thus $AA^T= C_x ^{-1}$... writing it out is helpful so e.g. you don't accidentally flip the ordering of $A$ and $A^T$.  Note that $A$ is not unique, though a common choice involves using Cholesky Factorization.